# “A person who sells the toys in the street”

Tags: word-request, nouns

> She often makes her children sleep for fear that  ___ should come into the street again.

That person sells toys such as balloon, doll, ball, bicycle, train, etc... traveling (especially along the street).

As you know, by seeing the toy seller in the street, our kids weep and insist on buying therefore we caring mother or father fear and make them sleep because we have no money to get them the toys.

[image: man with a display of balloons and toys for sale]

Comment: “street peddler”?

Comment: A [**hawker**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hawker) but selling anything, not just toys.

Comment: simply use "vendor" ?

Comment: I’ve heard the term *street vendor*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of this specific phenomenon (a traveling toy seller) having a name, but there are ways you could invoke similar ideas depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Literal interpretations could include "traveling salesman" or "solicitor" which are names for people who practice door-to-door sales tactics.

> She often makes her children sleep for fear that **the traveling toy salesman** should come into the street again.

If you are trying to evoke the idea of a neighborhood-roaming salesman who tends to attract the interest of kids, a common trope in the United States is the [Ice-Cream Truck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream_van).  They have a jingle they play that can be heard from a distance and causes plenty of parents to groan.

> She often makes her children sleep for fear that **the ice cream man** should come into the street again.

Answer (score 0):

You yourself answered your own question: a "toy seller" is a person who sells toys.

Comment: Can’t ‘a toy seller’ be a person whose shop on the street? I want a particular word for a person who sells toys, travelling from village to village, from places to places or from door to door.

Comment: I do not think English has such a word. "Wandering toy seller" would describe it.

Comment: _Pedlar_ or _hawker_ is the word for a person who walks about selling goods. There isn't a single word for a pedlar of toys.